# exec("ls") works. exec("other command") does not

Tags: php, exec

If I put this in my script:

```
$output = array();
exec("/var/www", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

I get an array of all the files in that folder.

However when I do this:

```
$output = array();
exec("../node_modules/less/bin/lessc ./default.less", $output);
var_dump($output);
```

The output I get is

> array(0) {}

If I run the same command in the command line (*from the same directory my php script is in*) it works fine.

I also tried absolute paths:

> /var/www/node_modules/less/bin/lessc /var/www/nodeless/default.less

Here is the permissions for these files:

> drwxr-xr-x  2 ftpuser  ftpuser    4096 2011-06-06 16:43 nodeless
>
> drwxr-xr-x  4 ftpuser  www-data   4096 2011-06-06 15:44 node_modules

Any ideas why I can't do it from PHP?

Comment: What's PHP's working directory relative to the PHP script?

Comment: use a full path not a relative one.

Comment: @icktoofay the script is in `/var/www/nodeless/less.php` the php site root is `/var/www` the executable I am trying to call is at `/var/www/node_modules/less/bin/lessc`

Comment: @John Isaacks, to find out where your script runs from, take a look at the output from [`getcwd()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php).

Comment: When you tested from the commandline, were you running as the same user as PHP does?

Comment: @Tomalak, no - not sure how to do that. I think PHP uses www-data but I ssh with a different user. But I did set www-data as the owner of the file I am trying to execute.

Comment: @John Isaacks, does `www-data` have `x` permission on all the directories leading to the file, and `x` permission on the file?

Comment: @Radu, I updated my answer to show the permissions for both directories.

Comment: @John Isaacks, how about `r` permission on the `default.less` file?

Comment: @Radu even if I set al the files to 0777 it still doesn't work. @Tomalak I don't believe there is a way to use `sudo` when executing commands from PHP.

Comment: @John, if you want to use `sudo`, you need to give `www-data` `sudo` privileges, to create a password for it, then to use `echo password | sudo -S command`.

Comment: @Radu, I will try this, do you know how to give www-data sudo privileges? Thanks.

Comment: @Radu, ok if I SSH as `www-data` the user PHP uses, I get **Permission denied**. I set www-data to sudoers list. I tried running the command with sudo and I get this: `/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory` Any ideas?

Comment: @Radu, that error message was because the $PATH was wrong. I reinstalled node.js and less from the www-data user. It now all works. :)

Comment: @John Isaacks, lessc needs node.js to run (as you can see from [the source](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/master/bin/lessc)). You need to install [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really owe finding the solution to my problem to the help from **Radu** and **Tomalak Geret'kal**. However as Radu's answer currently stands, it does not describe what fixed my issue. So I will explain it here.

I tried to SSH into the server using the same user as PHP (*www-data*) and execute the same command. I was given this error:

> /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

As it turns out when I first installed `node.js`, the instructions I followed told me to add the path to my **$PATH** environment variable. However that was a different user than *www-data*, so the path to node was not in my $PATH any longer when using the *www-data* user.

I am not expert in this area but I assumed that was likely the problem. So I started over following the [installation instructions for node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation), only this time as the *www-data* user.

Afterwards I could then execute the command on the command line as *www-data*. So I tried my PHP script again. It now worked as well.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use relative paths. Use `dirname(__FILE__)` to find the path of your PHP script, then build an absolute path from that. Example:

```
$lessc = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../node_modules/less/bin/lessc';
```

Answer (score 0):

We won't give you exact answer because we don't know how your server is configured, but you must determine what is the path PHP's in and then fix you paths appropriately. The best way is to use absolute paths, as they are always resolved correctly.

Comment: I updated my question. I tried with absolute paths. It works in command prompt but still not from within PHP.

Comment: Answer is still the same. Your path is not good and it's not PHP's fault. Your PHP interpreter may be in some weird directory and you may even not know where it is.

Comment: How is my path not good? I am using absolute paths now. It may not be PHP's fault, but they could at least give me some sort of clue as to why its not working instead of nothing at all. If I am using absolute paths why would it matter where my PHP interpreter is? I installed PHP the standard `apt-get install` way.